# Auto format replace Tag <p> to <ul><li> in tinymce when enter.why? and config?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tinymce

I have one content Code HTML in tinymce if have **dash**  content top row

```
<p>- body content</p>
```

When enter in tinymce then code html it becomes

```
<ul><li>body conten</li><li></li></ul>
```

if

```
<p>body content</p>
```

then enter no problem .why so ?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the text pattern plugin loaded?

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/textpattern/

The dash is markdown syntax for a list so perhaps you either have that setup via textpattern or some other plugin is doing this?

*Note:  TinyMCE by itself won't make that conversion so this is either a configuration issue, a plugin issue, or a server side code issue.*

Comment: thank you .  i don't register plugin textpattern then ok

Comment: If that solved the issue can you please accept this answer so others know the issue is resolved?